# SQL Insert multiple rows using stored procedure and xml parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

I've used a table valued parameter before, but I'm not sure how to use xml.

I do not know the best way to format my xml but I think I would try this:

```
<Car>  
   <Name>BMW</Name>  
   <Color>Red</Color>  
</Car>
```

Then I would pass the xml (one or more car) to the stored procedure and it would insert one row for each car I pass (with the name going in a name column etc..)

Does anyone know how to write the stored procedure?  (I'd usually try it myself but I don't have much time for testing T_T)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can shred the XML using the nodes function:

```
CREATE PROC ShredXML (@x xml)
AS BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TBL_TARGET (Name, Color)
    SELECT 
        x.y.value( 'Name[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)' ) AS Name,
        x.y.value( 'Color[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)' ) AS Color
    FROM @x.nodes('cars/car') x(y)
END


exec ShredXML @x = N'<cars><car><Name>BMW</Name><Color>Red</Color></car><car><Name>Audi</Name><Color>Green</Color></car></cars>'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alter PROC ShredXML (@x xml) 
AS 
BEGIN
If not exists (Select * from TBL_TARGET )
begin   
 INSERT INTO TBL_TARGET (Name, Color)
     SELECT x.y.value( 'Name[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)' )AS Name,x.y.value( 'Color[1]','VARCHAR(20)')AS Color FROM @x.nodes('cars/car') x(y)
end 
END   
exec ShredXML @x = N'<cars><car><Name>BMW</Name><Color>Red</Color></car><car><Name>Audi</Name><Color>Green</Color></car></cars>'
```